Mysql: have to insert data into table and read. no update or delete operations need to perform. Which storage engine will be good for table

This is the one of the table used in application which returns references of the ticket. "
ticket is primary and unique key in table.
Some times i am facing issue that record not available in table.
So i assume that read request comes before inserting the data into table.
The time difference of request for inserting data and reading the same is in milliseconds.
So i am not able to trace the issue why data is not available in table.
I want to try with storage engine change if any can increase the insert performance.

"i assume that read request comes before inserting the data into table" - then it's obvious that the data is not present. How should any database storage engine be able to read data that is not yet inserted?

as @NicoHaase states, if you read before you write then expect nothing. Share the code so folks can comment / suggest how to fix (if it is fixable). NB: no screenshots, a  copy/paste the code.

This is not something you solve in the database. If the reader needs to wait for the writer, you need to coordinate with some other mechanism.

InnoDB is best for virtually all scenarios; don't bother looking at any other engines.

Need more info to diagnose what you described.  Sounds like there are multiple connections and they are not playing fair with "transactions".
